# SQL Server Regex ~ equivalent

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, posix

How can I convert this script to be supported by sql server 2016, this script is made for postgreSQL

```
SELECT matricule FROM student WHERE matricule ~ regex
```

the regexp is dynamic and follows posix standard, in postgreSQL I use ~ to match it but in sql server it's not supported ! LIKE also doesn't do the job for all posix regexp .

Example:

- `^SAG*`: for selecting only students with registration code starting with SAG,
- `SAG(100|101)()*`: for selecting only students with registration code
  starting with SAG and followed by 100 or 101

Comment: Start with a basic SQL tutorial. You don't need a regex for this in the vast majority of DBMSs (including PostgreSQL), and it's covered in every SQL tutorial.

Comment: that was an example, the regexp is dynamic and follows posix standard, in postgreSQL I use ~ to match it but in sql server it's not supported ! LIKE also doesn't do the job.

Comment: That's not the question you asked. Provide a sample of an actual regex you use, sample data that it would be used on, and the results you'd expect to obtain from that data. We're more than willing to help, but you have to clearly state the issue and  give us the details. Misleading us by not providing actual details (or providing incorrect ones) wastes both your time (waiting for an answer) and ours (answering the question you asked instead of what you meant to ask).

Comment: i added examples to the description.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
where name like 'A%'
```

This will work in either database.  The `*` looks for 0 or more occurrences, so your regular expression is not doing what you say it is.

In either database, you can use `like` to do what you want:

```
where name like 'Ab%'
```

Note that type sensitivity depends on the collation of the string columns and default collation of the database.  So, this might match `'aB'`.

Comment: that was an example, the regexp is dynamic and follows posix standard, in postgreSQL I use ~ to match it but in sql server it's not supported ! LIKE also doesn't do the job for all posix regexp

Comment: @Mahamakni . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  If you have another question, then ask it as a *question* not in a comment.